# flutter: Putting a FlatButton with Column as child in an AppBar breaks layout

Tags: flutter

I have the following code for creating an BottomAppBar in my app, which works fine.

```
class MyBottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> rowContents = <Widget> [
      new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {

          },
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.menu),
              new Text("Feed")
            ],
          ),
      ),
      const Expanded(child: const SizedBox()),
      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {

        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.people),
            new Text("Profile")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];



    return new BottomAppBar(
      hasNotch: true,
      child: new Row(children: rowContents),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I want to use a `Column()` as a child of the `FlatButton()`, so that the `Text()` is shown below the `Icon()` and not next to it.

When I change `Row()` to `Column()`, I get the following result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `Column` widget fills in all the space possible. You can pass it a `mainAxisSize` of `mainAxisSize.min` to tell the widget to take up as little space as possible.

This is a revised version of your code that works as you want it:

```
class MyBottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> rowContents = <Widget> [
      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {

        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.menu),
            new Text("Feed")
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const Expanded(child: const SizedBox()),
      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {

        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.people),
            new Text("Profile")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];



    return new BottomAppBar(
      hasNotch: true,
      child: new Row(children: rowContents),
    );
  }
}
```